# Returning a variable from a foreach-loop ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to return a password from a foreach-loop to do some validations, but I can't get the password-variable to return. I keep getting errors. I do this in my controller.

My code:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(userModel user)
{
    ViewBag.Password = pwd.GetPassword(user);

    string password = "";
    foreach(var pwdR in ViewBag.Password.Rows)
    {
       password = pwdR[1];
    }
    return password; // Here I get this error: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'

    // VALIDATION CODE
    ....................
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(userModel user)
{
    ScryptEncoder enc = new ScryptEncoder();
    UserModel pwd = new UserModel();
    ViewBag.Password = pwd.GetPassword(user);

    string password = "";
    foreach(var pwdR in ViewBag.Password.Rows)
    {
       password = pwdR[1];
    }
    return password; // Here I get this error: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult'

    // VALIDATION CODE
    bool match = enc.Compare(user.pwd, password);

    if (match) 
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "You are now logged in.";
        return View();
    } else
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "Login failed.";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `ActionResult<string>` as a result. But anyway, it's really bad idea from security perspective to return your password on client side. Better run you validations on server side.

Comment: If you are trying to learn more about authentication in asp.net core it may be useful to get along with Microsoft documentation :)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @mike I've read and tried using Identity, but I have to use MySql for this project which complicates things alot. I've spent days trying to make register and login using Identity, but I ran into so much complications that I just decided to do it this way. I already have a finished database which I'm connecting to, so I don't want to create new tables. Everything would've been so much easier if I could just use a Sql database.

Comment: @AndrewSilver I'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: Can you pls explain what sense makes this code string password = "";
    foreach(var pwdR in ViewBag.Password.Rows)
    {
       password = pwdR[1];
    } ?

Comment: @Serge it takes the password from the viewbag index-number 1 and stores it in the variable password.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. But whar for each for?

Comment: @Serge I don't understand the question. Are you asking why I'm using foreach? It will search through every row in the array.

Comment: Yes, but I doesn't  do anything with it. It will  always assign the last row to the password. You can do it without foreach.

Comment: @Serge how? I've tried using "for" to no success.

Comment: Can you post some expalanations pls? what ViewBag.Password.Rows contain. Maybe post Row class. I am sure the most don' t understand what  the rows for? Why pwdR[1] but not pwdR[0]  or pwdR[2] And what are trying to validate.

Comment: @Serge ViewBag.Password contains username and password. In pwdR[0] is the username and in pwdR[1] is a hashed password. What I'm trying to do is compare the inputed password with the hashed password in the database. If they match then the user should be logged in.

Comment: Ok,Thanks. But why do you have many rows for one user?

Comment: @serge I only have one row for each user. I just don’t know of any other way to get the value. That’s how we’ve been thaught and I’ve googled to no avail on a different approach, but I can’t find any. Maybe i just suck at googling haha.

Comment: it is realy strange way to keep all uses in one viewbag. ViewBag only exists during one response preparation for one user.   another strange code - UserModel pwd = new UserModel(); ViewBag.Password = pwd.GetPassword(user); can you post this pwd.GetPassword() pls?

Comment: @Serge ofcourse. I updated the post now.

Comment: @Serge I solved it now. My mistake was here: "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username = @ Username AND Password = @ Password;". It should be like this: "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username = @ Username;". Because I'm doing the validation in the controller. I'm so dumb... Sorry for taking your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a big performance bug to load all users  and to find one you need.

Try this code

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(UserModel user)
{
    ScryptEncoder enc = new ScryptEncoder();

      var userNamePassword= GetUserNamePassword (user) ;

  if(  userNamePassword==null)
    ViewBag.Error = "Login failed. User is not found";
    return View();
}
    // VALIDATION CODE
    bool match = enc.Compare(userNamePassword.Password, password);

    if (match) 
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "You are now logged in.";
        return View();
    } else
    {
        ViewBag.Error = "Login failed.";
        return View();
    }
}
```

change your model class to this

```
 public class UserNamePasswordModel
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
```

and place this code somewhere near the Login action

```
private  UserNamePasswordModel GetUserNamePassword (UserModel user)
{

UserNamePasswordModel  userNamePassword= null;

var connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=xxxx; uid = xxxx;Password=xxxx;";
        
using   (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  var command =  new MySqlCommand("SELECT UserName, Password  FROM User WHERE Username = @Username", connection);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", user.Username);

        connection.Open();

       var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
           if reader.Read()
            {
             userNamePassword= new UserNamePasswordModel
             {
              Username=  reader.GetString(0),
               Password =   reader.GetString(1)
             };
            }
        }
        
        reader.Close();
    }
}
    return userNamePassword;
       
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks alot! This worked too. I really appreciate you taking your time! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

try returning Ok with password in it, something like: `return Ok(password);`

Comment: that removed the error, but the code under it is unreachable. I'm trying to do some validations after the password is returned in the same controller.

Comment: perhaps you could share more about the rest of the code and something about what type of validation you are trying to do

Comment: it's updated now. That's the entire code.